# Разделить cookie

Tags: java, cookie, tomcat, сессия

Есть скрипт который подключается на сайт.

Допустим есть **Сайт1** и **Сайт2** на которых подключен данный скрипт (Эти сайты абсолютно разные, никак не связанные между собой).
При загрузке данного скрипта сервер (Tomcat) ставит куку **id** сессии и соответственно даёт ему домен **site.com** (адрес сервера)и `path = /`.
После полной загрузки сайта, скрипт делает Ajax запрос на сервер (CORS настроен).

Проблема вся в том что: Я открываю **Сайт1**, куки поставились, все дела. Потом открываю **Сайт2** то получается так что куки поставленные на **Сайт1**, но с доменом сервера, будут те же и на **Сайт2**.

Я попытался разделить их при помощи `path` в куках, но это привело к тому что эту куку теперь не подхватывает Ajax.

Как еще можно разделить их?

Спасибо.